# Exception raised while adding an element into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, enumeration

I have an array list I am trying to add values into it and I am running into exception. 
I have used this code many times much still can't figure out what is creating this error, below is the code for your reference.

The line where I am using add method I get into a null pointer exception, 
All the above values are getting printed in console)

```
sid = new ArrayList<String>();
Enumeration e = Global.qtutlist.keys();
int qj=0; 
//iterate through Hashtable keys Enumeration
while(e.hasMoreElements())
{
    System.out.println("sid is key and its value id" );
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(e.nextElement().toString()));
    try
    {
        sid.add(e.nextElement().toString());
        System.out.println("lenght is "+ sid.size());
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("caught exception is"+ex.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us which exception happens in which line.

Comment: @all above Max have said it is nullpointerexception

Answer (score 5):

you are calling `nextElement()` twice in loop and checking once

make it as follows

```
while(e.hasMoreElements())
        {   String item = e.nextElement().toString()
            System.out.println("sid is key and its value id" );
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(item));
            try{
            sid.add(item);
            System.out.println("lenght is "+ sid.size());
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("caught exception is"+ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

If it shows `NumberFormatException` then one of the string isn't parsable to `int`

Answer (score 2):

You're calling

```
e.nextElement()
```

Twice. Store it in a variable and operate on that variable instead

```
while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
    Object o = e.nextElement();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In addition, isn't `Enumeration` generic? Parameterize it and then you won't have to store each value in a basic `Object` reference.

Comment: @Tom: True. I thought that's not the issue here, though

Comment: No, but the fact that `ArrayList` was properly parameterized while `Enumeration` was not seemed inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

You are using e.nextElement() twice. This can't work. Enumerations use the Iterator design pattern, which means that you may only access each element once, before the internal counter advances to the next object. Note that hasMoreElements() does not advance the cursor, only nextElement() does.

Store the result in a local variable and re-use that:

```
System.out.println("sid is key and its value id" );
String str = e.nextElement().toString();
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str));
try{
    sid.add(str);
    System.out.println("lenght is "+ sid.size());
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("caught exception is"+ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

e.nextElement() is null that is the reason and you are doing an toString() operation on null

Answer (score 0):

You invoke nextElement twice when you check item presence only once.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `e.hasMoreElements()` once and call `e.nextElement()` twice in the loop. Every call to `nextElement()` increments the internal marker, so every time, the number of elements in your enumeration is *odd*, you get an NPE.